# unity3d turn on off particle system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, particle-system

i am trying to turn on and off a particle system i created.
I attached it to a prefab.

The code I am using is as follows

```
public ParticleSystem waterGun;

void Update () {
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)){
        waterGun.enableEmission = true;
    }else if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W)){
        waterGun.enableEmission = false;
    }
}
```

I want the particle system to play in front of the fps when a key is held down and stop playing when it is pressed.

Comment: According to the [Unity3D documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem-enableEmission.html) this _should_ disable the emission. I take it this is not working for you?

Comment: unfortunately it is not, thats wats confusing me

Comment: Have you properly assigned the correct instance of the particle system to the `waterGun` field?

Comment: the waterGun prefab is given to it

Comment: Is it possible the `if`statement should be changed to `GetKeyDown` instead of `GetKey`? In your question, you say: `and stop playing when it is pressed.` This is not what happens here. Here, it'll stop playing when you release the button.

Answer (score 5):

Try using:

```
waterGun.Play();
```

and

```
waterGun.Stop();
```

And also, your logic is inverted, like Joetjah said.

Answer (score 0):

You say that the "waterGun prefab is given to it" but you should be assigning an instance of a particle system in the scene to waterGun, not the prefab. A prefab doesn't exist in the scene.